# countdown timer from the difference of start and dead line time values in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

if column A (start time) is Jan 1st 12:00 am if column B (deadline) is Jan 2nd 12:00 am, then I need column C (countdown)to show the time difference of 24 hours which should decrease to 0 hours in synchronization with real-time, so when the date is Jan 2nd 12:00 am the column C value is 0 and it has to refresh for every minute and show the time difference.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IF(REGEXMATCH(
 TEXT(IF(NOW()>=A2:A, NOW()-B2:B, ), "[h]:mm:ss"), "^-.*"), 
 TEXT(IF(NOW()>=A2:A, NOW()-B2:B, ), "[h]:mm:ss"), )))
```

[image]